# Using for IDbConnection/IDbTransaction safe to use?

Tags: c#, vb.net, transactions, database-connection, using-statement

While my assumption may seem to sound subjective, after some research, I found that it's not uncommon to find developers who favour a dummy `Try/Catch` instead of using the [Using statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htd05whh.aspx) for `IDbConnection/IDbTransaction` processing (Close/Commit/Rollback).

This holds true for even some of the most seasoned developers and some new ones. I am intentionally not going to reference any of the question on StackOverflow or forum links as an example, so people don't get offended. From [what I found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/641660/will-a-using-statement-rollback-a-database-transaction-if-an-error-occurs), [Using](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htd05whh.aspx) statement is [safe to use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7552297/does-using-var-connection-new-sqlconnectionconnectionstring-still-close) (no pun intended).

Is there anything wrong with it? Consider the following code:

```vb
Public Sub Commit()
  Dim cn As IDbConnection = {CREATE_CONNECTION}
  Dim tran As IDbTransaction = Nothing

  cn.Open()
  Try
    tran = cn.BeginTransaction
    'run some queries here
    tran.Commit()
  Catch ex As Exception
    If Not tran Is Nothing Then tran.Rollback()
    Throw
  Finally
    cn.Close()
  End Try
End Function
```

Assume `{CREATE_CONNECTION}` is place holder for a `Sub` that creates a connection, depending on the database vendor, written according to all possible best practices and does not need more improvement.

Is there a reason why the above code cannot be rewritten as such:

```vb
Using cn As IDbConnection = {CREATE_CONNECTION}
  cn.Open()
  Using tran As IDbTransaction = cn.BeginTransaction
    'run some queries here
    tran.Commit()
  End Using
End Using
```

**?**

Clearly, version #2 is more intuitive to what it's doing. But perhaps I am missing something important here? Things like vendor-specific implementations of data access libraries, that do not call `Transaction.Commit` and/or `Connection.Close` on `Dispose` internally? Is this approach being decommissioned in the near future, or not regarded as *clear enough* in modern programming pattern/best practices? Mono/mobile apps dev tools lacking debug support for `Using` keyword?

I am looking for any kind of answer to support or deny the point. Preferably the one with quotes to original documentation, something like `Do not use Using with IDbTransaction when ...`. Links to blogs or personal experience are okay too.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I'm entirely with you on the connection; that should be `using`, and there is no need for the explicit `Close()`. The transaction is a little bit trickier; the code shown is certainly overkill at the moment, but it is not entirely defined that `Dispose()` should do a rollback. Actually, that *is* what tends to happen in every implementation I've looked at, but it is slightly vexing that even `DbTransaction` (which most providers use) doesn't actually do this. Contrast to `TransactionScope` where it is explicitly defined that a `Dispose()` without a commit counts as a rollback. Because of that, I *tend* to use (excuse the C#):

```
using(var conn = GetOpenConnection())
using(var tran = conn.BeginTransaction()) {
    try {
        // TODO: do work
        tran.Commit();
    } catch {
        tran.Rollback();
        throw;
    }
}
```

which is somewhere between the two in terms of complexity. It isn't messing around with `null`-checks, at least.

Comment: That explains it, thanks. Definitely more clear than my version #1. Also +1 for `GetOpenConnection`, I was also leaning towards incorporating `cn.Open()` into some `CreateAndOpenConnection`, as it seems redundant to call every time.

Comment: If the connection to the database is closed, will the transaction still get rolled back? I understand you are more worried about possible locking.

Answer (score 14):

What you're seeing is developers coding according to the documentation (a "Good Thing"). The base class DbTransaction (used for most data providers' transaction implementations) states clearly in [its documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bf2cw321.aspx):

> Dispose should rollback the transaction. However, the behavior of Dispose is provider specific, and should not replace calling Rollback.

Comment: Thanks. MS should definitely make it clearer on the actual interface.